# Array Index Out of Bounds Exception - RMI DynamicClient

Tags: java, rmi

```
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;
import java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class DynamicClient {
    public DynamicClient (String[] args) throws Exception {
        Properties p = System.getProperties(); 
        String url = p.getProperty("java.rmi.server.codebase"); 
        Class ClasseClient = RMIClassLoader.loadClass(url,"ClientDistant");
        Constructor [] C = ClasseClient.getConstructors();
        C[0].newInstance( new Object[] {args} );
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.setSecurityManager( new RMISecurityManager() );
        try {
            DynamicClient cli = new DynamicClient(args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This code is supposed to dynamically charge the class ClientDistant from a web server and execute the treatment, however it displays an error message:

```
 C:\Users\DELL\Desktop>java -Djava.security.policy=client.policy  -Djava.rmi.serv
 er.useCodebaseOnly=false  -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=http://localhost:8080/RMI/
 DynamicClient

 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

where RMI is a directory's in the java web application named RMI ( I m using GlassFish server).
Any solutions to load ClientDistant and execute its treatment?

Comment: You need to debug and see if you are getting any constructor.

Comment: Same error nothing changed

Comment: Perhaps you should print the actual stacktrace (e.printStackTrace()) so you now where the exception is coming from. Maybe it's not even coming from C being empty.

Comment: I found the solution. you should replace every args occurence with argv , and make the class ClientDistant public

Comment: Please don't use tabs when formatting code in stackoverflow. The resulting indentation is malformed. I've fixed this for you.

Comment: Yes, what fixed it most likely is making the class public, as `getContructors` will return only return public constructors. The argument name `args` or `argv` doesn't make a difference.